# STM32 Nucleo-WL55JC1 UART reading wrong

Tags: c, stm32, uart

I'm trying to read my GNSS module using STM32 Nucleo-WL55JC1. Here's my main loop code first

```
while (1)
{
      uint8_t buff[500];

      HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, buff, strlen((char*)buff), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, buff, strlen((char*)buff), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
}
```

When I run the code my serial monitor only print few messages and then it freezes

```
$PSTMVER,GNSSLIB_8.4.18.25_CP_ARM*07  
$GPTXT,DEFAULT LIV3FL CONFIGURATION*12  
$PSTMVER,OS20LIB_4.4.0_ARM*40  
$PSTMVER,GPSAPP_2.11.0_CP_LIV3FL_RC9_ARM*20  
$PSTMVER,BINIMG_4.6.15_CP_LIV3FL_RC9_ARM*27
```

Then I changed the receive timeout to `1000` it started outputing some NMEA data, but as you can see it mixed up with other messages

```
$PSTMCPU,20.86,-1,98*4F  
$GPRMC,060732.000,V,0745.75046,S,11023.31916,E,,,071222,,,N*64  $GPGGA,060732.000,0745.75046,S,11023.31916,E,0,00,99.0,172.57,M,0.0,M11023.31916,E,060731.000,V,N*54
```

Then I unplugged and try to plug the MCU and now it only looping on this message

```
$PSTMVER,GPSAPP_2.11.0_CP_LIV3FL_RC9_ARM*20  
$PSTMVPSTMVER,OS20LIB_4.4.0_ARM*40  
$PSTMVER,GPSAPP_2.11.0_CP_LIV3FL_RC9_ARM*20  
$PSTMVPSTMVER,OS20LIB_4.4.0_ARM*40  
$PSTMVER,GPSAPP_2.11.0_CP_LIV3FL_RC9_ARM*20  
$PSTMVPSTMVER,OS20LIB_4.4.0_ARM*40
```

I've tried using the same module on ESP it prints the message correctly

```
$PSTMCPU,21.69,-1,98*4F
$GPRMC,062153.000,V,0745.76371,S,11023.30606,E,,,071222,,,N*6C
$GPGGA,062153.000,0745.76371,S,11023.30606,E,0,02,99.0,189.71,M,0.0,M,,*77
$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
$GNGSA,A,1,26,27,,,,,,,,,,,99.0,99.0,99.0*1F
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.0,99.0,99.0*1E
$GPGSV,2,1,05,26,53,342,32,27,39,189,27,22,35,019,,23,14,149,*75
$GPGSV,2,2,05,21,07,251,,,,,,,,,,,,,*4E
$GLGSV,2,1,06,70,70,053,,74,33,309,,71,29,352,,69,26,142,27*6F
$GLGSV,2,2,06,80,15,158,,85,11,205,,,,,,,,,*69
$GPGLL,0745.76371,S,11023.30606,E,062153.000,V,N*5F
```

This is my first time using STM32 IDE and its HAL (I only use Arduino IDE before) so I kinda lost why my output is really different compared with the ESP.

**Edit 1**

As chux - Reinstate Monica's suggests I've modified the code to the following

```
uint8_t buff[500];

ret = HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, buff, sizeof buff , HAL_MAX_DELAY);
while(ret != HAL_OK); // Continue when Receive returns HAL_OK
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, buff, sizeof buff, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

The stuck problem is still there, but the output now changes to

```
$PSTMVER,GNSSLIB_8.4.18.25_CP_ARM*07
$GPTXT,DEFAULT LIV3FL CONFIGURATION*12
$PSTMVER,OS20LIB_4.4.0_ARM*40
$PSTMVER,GPSAPP_2.11.0_CP_LIV3FL_RC9_ARM*20
$PSTMVER,BINIMG_4.6.15_CP_LIV3FL_RC9_ARM*27
$PSTMVER,SWCFG_8306532d*33
$PSTMVER,STAGPSLIB_6.0.0_ARM*5A
$PSTMVER,STA8090_822bc043*61
$GPTXT,(C)2000-2018 ST Microelectronics*29
$GPTXT,DEFAULT LIV3FL CONFIGURATION*12
$PSTMSWCONFIG,1,0,12,000205f105070a0a0e0d0c0b0a090608070203630e110c04180c0155030110500f00000f071402050a40fffffffffffffffffffff (stuck here)
```

Reflashing without unplug and plugging the MCU

```
$GNGSA,A,3,03,16,32,27,26,22,,,,,,,1.9,1.0,1.6*26
$GNGSA,A,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,1.9,1.0,1.6*22
$GPGSV,3,1,10,16,58,305,23,27,53,179,23,32,47,086,23,22,46,034,22*72
$GPGSV,3,2,10,26,39,354,20,10,30,157,14,08,25,206,13,03,14,310,27*7B
$GPGSV,3,3,10,31,12,021,,21,10,237,,,,,,,,,*7E
$GLGSV,2,1,08,70,72,122,,71,48,350,,84,23,127,,74,22,326,*6C
$GLGSV,2,2,08,75,19,269,19,85,17,189,,69,11,151,18,80,11,144,19*6B
$GPGLL,0745.76098,S,11023.30836,E,065605.000,A,A*4D
$PSTMCPU,36.35,-1,98*40
$G (stuck here)
```

Comment: `while(ret != HAL_OK);` looks like an infinite look when `while(ret != HAL_OK);`.  Is that really your intent?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm just making sure that `HAL_UART_Transmit` won't run before it finished receiving data. Removing `while(ret != HAL_OK);` didn't change anything since it still freezes after first call.

Comment: HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, buff, sizeof buff, HAL_MAX_DELAY) will not return until all 500 characters have been read. I doubt this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

`strlen((char*)buff)` is invalid as the contents of `buff` are indeterminate.
Consider `HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, buff, sizeof buff, HAL_MAX_DELAY);`

.. and use the return value of `HAL_UART_Receive()` to determine success level.

`HAL_UART_Transmit()` should only attempt to transmit the number of characters received, not `strlen((char*)buff)`.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. I've implemented your solution but the stuck problem is still exists. However, when I reflash my STM it different message before freezing again. Kindly check my edited answer.